# How to split a string with the uppercase character in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to separate a string with the occurrence of the Uppercase letters.
Suppose I have an string like "IAmABoy".I want the resulting strings like

```
I
Am
A
Boy.
```

How to do this? Is there any sample code?  Please show me the way to do this.

Comment: Do not add answers if they are comments. Instead, use the "add comment" link to add comments to an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something simple like just iterating over each character? Assuming inputString and outputString are NSStrings something like this should work:

```
  NSUInteger length = [inputString length];
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    char c = [inputString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (i > 0 && c >= 65 && c <=90)
    {
      [outputString appendFormat:@"\n%c", c];
    }
    else
    {
      [outputString appendFormat:@"%c", c];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Carson for you reply.But the line

`[outputString appendFormat:@"\n%c", c];`

througing some exception.I have modify your code to the following one and it seems to be working for me.

---

`NSString *inputString=@"IAmABoy";
 NSString *outputString;
 NSString *string=@"";
 NSUInteger length = [inputString length];
 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
  char c = [inputString characterAtIndex:i];
  if (i > 0 && c >= 65 && c <=90)
  {
   //[outputString appandFormate:@"\n%c", c];
   outputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
   string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",string,@" ",outputString];
   NSLog(@"%@", string);
  }
  else
  {
   //[outputString appendFormat:@"%c", c];
   outputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
   //NSLog(@"%@",outputString);
   string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",string,outputString];
   NSLog(@"%@", string);
  }
 }`

---

Thanx once again to all for your cooperations and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest importing a Regex library or taking a look at NSScanner.

Answer (score 0):

look into RegexKitLite

Answer (score 0):

Try using -rangeOfCharacterFromSet: and splitting the string based on where you find the upper-case characters.

Answer (score 0):

`extension String {
  public func stringFromPascalCase() -> String {
    return self.characters.enumerate().map { (String($1).componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet()).joinWithSeparator("").isEmpty && $0 > 0) ? " \($1)" : "\($1)" }.joinWithSeparator("")
  }
}`

this should do the trick.

`let x = "EastMayerDrive".stringFromPascalCase()
print(x) /// East Mayer Drive`