# Objective C : Separate words in a string and join again

Tags: ios, objective-c, tokenize

I have a string say `@"DidNotTurnUp"`. I want to write a function which will take this string as an input and should output `@"Did Not Turn Up"`. What would be the best way to do this? How to separate the words in a string based on capital letters? Help appreciated.

Comment: Separating: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806879/876283, Joining: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12156814/876283

Comment: Look for capital letters in the string and insert space before every capital letter…hope this the logic you are looking for..

Comment: You can use the regular expression for the same. Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322498/insert-or-split-string-at-uppercase-letters-objective-c

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Please stop doing this. Your answer is pretty much visible. Reported as _not constructive_

Comment: What is this today?? Three people just copying the accepted answer of the linked-to question without any attribution.

Comment: So.. What do you want in the case of DOESNotTurnUp? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a category on NSString that will do what you want.

```
@implementation NSString (SeparateCapitalizedWords)

-(NSString*)stringBySeparatingCapitalizedWords
{
    static NSRegularExpression * __regex ;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSError * error = nil ;
        __regex = [ NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[\\p{Uppercase Letter}]" options:0 error:&error ] ;
        if ( error ) { @throw error ; }
    });

    NSString * result = [ __regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self options:0 range:(NSRange){ 1, self.length - 1 } withTemplate:@" $0" ] ;
    return result ;
}

@end
```

Comment: This gives the result " id ot urn p".

Comment: you're right! I fixed it.

Comment: I think the other regex might be better: any lower case letter followed by an uppercase one... but I would prefer this code structure in production. Depends how often you will be calling it.

Comment: +1 for using `\p{Uppercase Letter}` which should also cover non-ASCII uppercase letters such as Ä, Ǣ, Я.

Comment: Ok... I think this regex works better than (a-z)(A-Z), since this one will handle "IAmNewHere" --> "I Am New Here" for example.

Comment: `result` ends up containing the initial word uncapitalized. So if you're trying to generate a display name from, say, an obj-c property name such as `myValue`, you end up with lowercase `my`.

`return [result capitalizedString]` fixes this, with final output as "My Value".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *YourString=@"YouAreAGoodBoy";
NSString *outString;
NSString *string=@"";
NSUInteger length = [YourString length];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    char c = [YourString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (i > 0 && c >= 65 && c <=90)
    {
        outString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",string,@" ",outString];
    }
    else
    {
        outString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",string,outString];

    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Hope this code is useful for you .

Comment: I love this answer, it's original. One side note deserves mention though; in ASCII chars between 65 & 90 represent the uppercase letters hence the `if` condition.

Comment: "%c" works only with ASCII characters. You should use at least "%C" to make it work with UTF-16 characters (ä, €, ...). And there are uppercase letters which are not in the ASCII range such as Ä, Ǣ, Я.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"ThisStringIsJoined";
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([a-z])([A-Z])" 
    options:0 
    error:NULL];
NSString *newString = [regexp 
    stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string 
    options:0 
    range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) 
    withTemplate:@"$1 $2"];
NSLog(@"Changed '%@' -> '%@'", string, newString);
```

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322720/2842382, try this